# Which programming language is used to develop ArcGIS Desktop application?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c++

I just wanted to understand which programming language is used to develop the ArcGIS Desktop application, through my initial research I got to know that ArcGIS Desktop was created by using C++.

I just wanted to confirm if that is the case.

Comment: During one of my ESRI courses the instructor mentioned that it is written in C++

Answer (score 1):

From an older version (9.2) of the ArcGIS architecture documentation (you can do a quick search for some of the following text to find the relevant resources - I don't want to link a PDF download):

> ArcObjects is a set of platform-independent software components,
>   written in C++, that provides services to support GIS applications on
>   the desktop in the form of thick and thin clients and on the server.
>
> As stated, the language chosen to develop ArcObjects was C++; in
>   addition to this language, ArcObjects makes use of the Microsoft
>   Component Object Model.

The 'thick and thin clients' (ArcMap, ArcGIS Server) were also created using C++, although I can't find any authoritative documentation to back this up aside from a mention in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS).